# Hot Towel, Durandal SPA, Breeze Angular templates for VBNet?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, single-page-application

So it appears that there are not any prebuilt VBNET versions of the Hot Towel, Durandal Breeze Angular Templates for VS2012. But since those templates really just make use of client side libraries with MVC I should be able to wire up my own VBNET MVC version with said libraries/frameworks, right? Apologies if this has been asked before but i did not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Hot Towel SPA template via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HotTowel/).